# Why did all sites turn orange?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

What happened here? It used to be blue.

The primary colour has changed network wide it appears. The Ask a question button is orange on a selected site I just randomly tested, as was also pointed out by Animuson in the comments.

[image]

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Fixed!

We’ve got a new [theming API in Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/product/guidelines/theming/) that was leaking a bit. Funnily enough, all the themes we happened to test via smoke tests already had orange buttons so we didn't catch it.

And before everyone shouts about visual regression testing, yeah. I agree. We're working on that too