# Some per-site-metas are orange - again?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, per-site-meta, regression

Two designed sites I checked have their per-site meta orange again:

[image: rpg meta]

[image: puzzling meta]

However, Literature's meta is not:

[image: lit meta]

Looks like a regression of [Why did all sites turn orange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367641/) - as far as I can tell with spot-checks, only the metas of sites with custom designs with a *meta.stackexchange.com domain ([Meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and [Meta SU](https://meta.superuser.com/) are fine).

Comment: Seems to hit the sites with site designs, but not the others? IPS meta is still normal too, workplace se has the orange meta....

Comment: Having a look. No secret that we've been touching some behind-the-scenes theming stuff, and it's proving incredibly tricky to test these. On it!

Comment: @NickCraver Joke's getting old - pick a different color, please ;)

Comment: I vote for Purple everywhere :)

Comment: Honestly, I would love purple @DavidPostill.

Comment: Orange reminds me of B&Q, where my wife is doing too much overtime coutesy of COVID, and Easy(delayed)Jet, the friend of airport bars and fast-food joints:(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fixed! We had a variable rename go sideways on us. Those metas that inherit the default meta theming have now been restored to their former *glory*.