# Did the color contrast of closed question box just change?

Tags: support, design, dark-mode

Did the box color above closed questions change?

Is this a bug somehow related to the recent [color bug from the theming API in Stacks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367643)? Or is the current color meant to remain? I seem to notice the current color scheme degraded contrast and readability of text inside the box.

[image]

Comment: @Glorfindel just [confirmed by Ben Kelly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367707/post-notice-background-color-seems-to-have-gone-on-walkabout/367762#comment1225494_367762) here: *"This issue is not related, but was introduced with the same release. We already have a PR in progress [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks/pull/719) if you're interested in following along"*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but we've *just* pushed live a few tweaks to address the contrast of these colors in dark mode. Here's how the box looks as of the time of this post:

[image]

We're not quite 100% satisfied with the algo we're using across *all* of our colors in dark mode, but we wanted to at least improve it for now and not let perfect be the enemy of good.

Comment: But imperfect certainly isn't it's friend either. Due to time constraints there exists a limit to the research time available, but Google and Adobe have extensive experience and documented tools for creating accessable content across various devices; dark or light mode. --- Check out Adobe's open source solution, with light/dark switcher at top of the webpage: https://spectrum.adobe.com/page/principles/ https://opensource.adobe.com/spectrum-css/button-over-background.html