# Is it intentional that the question titles on per-site metas are now orange?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, per-site-meta

Looks like this again [Some per-site-metas are orange - again?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367706/273494) except it is the link styling and not the other parts of the page.

Sites I visited with the issue: ELL, EL&U, The Workplace.

Comment: I noticed this but not before I noticed that the main site links are all red on ELU main when they used to be a [muted grey](https://web.archive.org/web/20220327043127/https://english.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: We bumped our design system dependency but neglected to update some CSS variable names. This should be fixed within the next hour.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nope, it's not intentional. We updated the [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design) dependency but neglected to update the names of CSS variables referenced in the Stack Overflow codebase that had changed from `--theme-question-*` to `--theme-post-*`. This resulted in incorrect theme colors being applied to post summaries in certain contexts. We've shipped a fix and this issue should be resolved now.