# Why is the "load new answers" link so low contrast in this orange top bar notification?

Tags: bug, design, accessibility, notification-bar

I ran into this top bar notification earlier. The orange looks really off on GD.SE but I can understand a bright color would be used to make it visible. It left me wondering if it was related to the [recent orange incident](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367641/why-did-all-sites-turn-orange).

What seems more problematic is how low contrast the "load new answers" is.

Is this intentional for some reason or a simple accessibility oversight?

[image: Top bar notification]

Comment: Looks like oversight to me.

Comment: When does this banner get displayed? I don't think I've ever seen that before!

Comment: @zcoop98 I have the "too many tabs open" syndrome. I had two tabs open on the same meta page, answered in one of them and the other tab displayed the bar some time later. Fairly easy to science if you want to see it!

Comment: It's just a really old banner that people forget even exists because it's not supposed to get used anymore, so nobody ever tests it. We should probably just nuke it, I'm not sure why that code still even exists.

Comment: @animuson Seems like an answer to me! Thanks :)